# Polyglott notebooks: Metadata file 'nuget:Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Kql,*-*' could not be found

Tags: c#, azure, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to create a new Polyglot notebook for Kusto queries. However I am receiving this error.

```
Error: (1,5): error CS0006: Metadata file 'nuget:Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Kql,*-*' could not be found
```

I just added a new C# cell with this single line

```cs
 #r "nuget:Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Kql,*-*"
```

In other notebooks it is working fine. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that I accidentally copied a leading space before `#r`.

```cs
 #r "nuget:Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Kql,*-*" // Error
#r "nuget:Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Kql,*-*"  // No error
```